# Soft keyboard type for a particular input box in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am creating an App with phonegap framework in IOS. I have a few input boxes which are created through phonegap in html/javascript. I want to have soft keyboard of type [UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress] for one of the input boxes.

My code in AppDelegate.h is as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField* textField;
- (void) setKeyboardType: (UIKeyboardType)newType;
```

And for AppDelegate.m, it is as follows:

```
@synthesize  textField;

//function definition
- (void) setKeyboardType: (UIKeyboardType) newType  
{  
    //NSLog(@"setKeyboardType: %@", newType);
    textField.keyboardType = newType;  
}
```

and called from another function like follows:

```
[self setKeyboardType: (UIKeyboardType) UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```

This code is not working for any of the input boxes. Plus, how can i put the condition for that particular input box to have this type. input box ID is available. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is show a different keyboard set for your inputs, check [HTML5 input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp).

For example, when you set the type of your input to email, iPhone puts an @ key to keyboard, so it's a bit easier to type.

```
<input type="email" />
```

or when you set it to number, it shows the numeric keyboard

```
<input type="number" />
```

HTML5 input types are supported in other platforms as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the 'email' type on the html text field - `<input type="email" />` ?